# Could not find Get method for FacebookClient in MVC 4.0

Tags: facebook-graph-api, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-oauth

i am not able to find **`Get`** method for **`FacebookClient`** object in MVC 4.0 C# (VS2010).
please refer following screen:

[image]

I am using `DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients` and refer following tutorial to get friend list from facebook:
http://blue-and-orange.net/articles/facebook/facebook-friends-listing-in-aspnet-mvc-4/

Comment: I have worked with every version of facebook client developed by microsoft or other parties. THEY SUCK!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot you are using an older version of the SDK, a version prior to version 6. Starting on version 6 of the SDK the FacebooklClient class only accepts a single argument in addition to the default constructor. So prior to V6 you can pass in the `appId` and the `appSecret`. Starting on V6 you only need to pass the `accessToken`. I think pre-V6 versions implemented OAuth 1.0. The V6 version implements OAuth 2.0.

To resolve your issue, you should [get the latest version from NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/Facebook) or [get the source from GitHub](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/). [This tutorial](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/web/getting-started) can get you started.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. let me check with latest version.